# Cabal sandbox library path

Tags: haskell, path, ghc, cabal, lib

When I run `cabal install` in my sandbox project, I get

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSzlib-0.6.1.2-GcLmGV5PElZD6CJvjR9umm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSasync-2.1.1.1-2GwQEYzLBsdIBCHbNA3HGy
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSnetwork-uri-2.6.1.0-GzRvaV3udR3JtWfa3CLYOw
```

It turns out I have the lib:

```
locate HSzlib
```

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.0.2/libHSzlib-0.6.1.2-GcLmGV5PElZD6CJvjR9umm-ghc8.0.2.so

But I think that cabal doesn't find it, how to make it find it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do:

cabal install zlib --reinstall --force-reinstalls

cabal install async --reinstall --force-reinstalls

cabal install network-uri --reinstall --force-reinstalls

and relaunch the install.